# Can I port from ionic app to react native or reuse ionic code inside react native as it is?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, ionic-framework, react-native

I have one app written in ionic. If I learn react native, can I reuse the javascript code from ionic app? I mean all the UI, navigation, animation part. I know that in ionic the android toolbar deep integration is lacking compare to react native. But if I just copy paste the js and css in react, will it work? Anybody has done anything similar ? Is there some port option available anywhere ?

[image: Consider the hamburger menu]

Answer (score 6):

> But if I just copy paste the js and css in react, will it work?

No, it will not work -they are completely different frameworks. You can reuse any Javascript code that is not related to UI but for the UI you'll have to use React-Native components.

That said, copy-pasting won't work out of the box. You'll have to *migrate*.